# Opening Realm Dashboard on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, realm, realm-object-server

I'm trying to setup Realm Object Server on Amazon EC2. 
I've used the public AMI on North Virginia, and I have a running instance. I'm doing all this from Europe as most of my users are in the USA.

Now I'm trying to access ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9080.
I've tried to open the different ports as indicated but I feel that what I've done is incorrect.

[image]

I've also tried to open all traffic but I still have a timeout on the page. I'm probably doing something wrong here, I'm not sure what.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying out our AWS AMI!  It would be helpful to know the AMI ID that you ran, as that can help us track down problems for others.  In fact, we've released new AMIs this morning.  Check our website for the latest available AMI IDs.

In the meantime, can you check if the `realm-object-server` service is running?  You can check this via SSH and by running:

```
sudo service realm-object-server status
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I just solved my silly - I guess - issue, about to post it now...

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make things work!
I guess my issue is that I was somehow on the wrong security group.

When looking at your running instances, be sure to hit your security group at the right of the instance row, in order to be able to configure the correct one.

Then, configure a Custom TCP Rule with port 9080.

That's it!